# How to switch off explore by touch for some accessibility service

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, accessibility, accessibilityservice, talkback

How i can switch off explore by touch for some accessibility service,for example for google talkback,if i know package of this service. I try to change preferences of this service,because i know,that in talkback use PreferenceFragment key,which developers of talkback use for it,but it seems,that it creates new preferences xml file. I tryed to use:

`Context c=createPackageContext("com.google.android.marvin.talkback", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences p =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);\
p.edit().putBoolean("pref_explore_by_touch", false).commit();`

But it not works. Also i tryed get access to /data/data/com.google.android.marvin.talkback/,but list of files in this directory is null,and file can't read. I grant write/read_external_storage permissions. My phone is not rooted. How to modify accessibilityServiceInfo of some service or change it preferences programatically. At least how to do this for talkback Thanks everybody very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If any service requests explore by touch, the framework turns it on. It's not possible to forcibly turn it off from another process.

Apps also cannot change one another's preferences.

Comment: But my girlfriend have braille keyboard,which was wrote only for her and before implementation braille keyboard by google,and it catch all touching and gestures with one or more fingers,even if talkback is switch on and it works only for original talkback,so it exists some way,to modify settings of talkback or some another way,to switch off explore by touch and catch motionevents so,as it works without talkback. But how to do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without rebuilding TalkBack. That's why we implemented the Braille keyboard inside the TalkBack process. If you find a way to do it, I'd love to know how.